# Running cypress tests in docker image cypress/base:17.3.0 gives error ''CertVerifyProcBuiltin for ws14.hotjar.com failed'

Tags: cypress

I am running my tests with this docker image cypress/base:17.3.0. I got plenty of this kind of error even if the tests are passing... Any idea in order to fix them?

```
[33:0614/080128.399356:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(681)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for ws14.hotjar.com failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (OU=Cypress Proxy Server Certificate,O=Cypress Proxy CA,L=Internet,ST=Internet,C=Internet,CN=ws14.hotjar.com) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found
```

Comment: This looks like a known issue relating to cypress. There is more info here https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/22128

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an electron headless browser issue.

Try setting your headless browser to chrome.

> cypress run --headless --browser chrome